# CRUD in Typescript with mongoose - query param checking

Tags: typescript, mongoose, crud

I want to add document to my DB collection only after checking all the `req.query` is like my `IGroupDocument` on the controller before inserting.

What is the best practice for this?

IGroupDocument:

```
import { Document, Model } from "mongoose";

export interface IGroup {

    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age?: number;
    email: string,
    dateOfEntry?: Date;
}

export interface IGroupDocument extends IGroup, Document {}
```

Controller:

```
function create(req: Request, res: Response) {
// req.query validation: if firstName, lastName and email exist and type string, and then make a document from req.query call newGroup.
    GroupModel.create(newGroup)
    res.send(`${req.query.name} created`)
}
```

Comment: You should at least provide some code sample for us to see what you  are currently struggling with exactly. Are you using plain javascript with mongoose library? Do you want to do the validation on controller level or on schema level?

Comment: Sorry, I've Fixed the question. now its more clear

Comment: Well, no. You didn't even include code where you want to store anything to a DB. You also didn't include any code related to `IGroupDocument`.  You didn't even include what should be checked at all. Should it be checked that some query param is a string, has a certain length, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for yout attention! is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read query parameters from request object like following:

```
const { firstName, lastName, email } = req.query;
```

You can then pass these query parameters to your document create function like:

```
GroupModel.create({firstName, lastName, email});
```

The validation should take part in your mongoose schema. Since you did not include it, I just created a sample schema myself:

```
  const groupSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true }
  })
```

**Notes:**

- Passing values which are used for creating an object in query params is definitely a bad practice. You should pass them as the request body in a `POST` request.
- You cannot call `res.send('${req.query.name} created')` directly after calling the `create` function. This returns a promise, which should be awaited. You can just use `await GroupModel.create(...)` and define the function as `async`.
- You included `req.query.name` in your response, which is a query parameter that wasn't even used before. You should probably use a property from the `awaited` promise value.